# Place a Visual Studio project in a git repository and add a remote (bare?) origin on networkdrive

Tags: git, git-bash, visual-studio-2022, git-gui

I have a visual studio solution I have been working on.
The project may actually be more use full than I fist anticipated, so I want place it in a local git repository.

I also want to make a remote origin (bare repository) on an other (backed-up network) drive.

I have seen a zillion explanations, here on stack and else where, but when I try them the they don't seem to have desired result (don't track, can't push, etc.)

If someone has the correct commands in order of appearance I would be most grateful.

Say my project lives on "D:\projects\myapp"
and I want the remote on "G:\remotes\myapp"

The tools at my disposal are:
VS2022 community edition
GitGUI version 2.34.1.windows.1
GitBash version 4.4.23

UPDATE: I made a test project to try Jessehouwings solution:
Turn my project folder into a Git repo:
[image: ProjectToGitRepo]
Add Ignore and add the project files:
[image: AddFiles]
First commit:
[image: Commit]
So far so good:[image: CommitCreated]

Then create a bare repository on my backup-ed storage drive:
[image: CreateRemote]

Add remote to the project repo:
[image: LinkLocalAndRemote]

Try to push some changes error message
[image: VisualStudioNoCanDo]

What did I do wrong?
It looks like the path to the remote is not correct:
[image: ErrorMessage]

But how do I specify a local drive there?

Comment: I assume you got the local repo working? Running `git init` in the solution root, followed by the addition of a `.gitignore`, `git add .` and commit. Then setting up the bare repo `git init --bare` in an empty folder, adding the bare repo as remote to the local one `git remote add local //server/path/to/bare/repo/`.

Comment: So what isn't working, what did you try? Doesn't it work locally? Doesn't it work to the network share? Are you seeing any errors? Does it work when using the commandline? Doesn't it work inside visual studio? What kind of path to the remote origin did you try? UNC? Mapped drive? NFS? something else?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. Helps a lot to give you better guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the script below. Most important part, is to use `/` for your remote path.

```
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest>md repo
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest>cd repo
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/JesseHouwing/gittest/repo/.git/

C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>notepad readme.md
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>git add readme.md
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>git commit -m "readme"
[main (root-commit) 293503d] readme
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 readme.md

C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>cd ..
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest>md remote
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest>cd remote

C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\remote>git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/JesseHouwing/gittest/remote/

C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\remote>cd ..\repo
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>git remote add network C:/Users/JesseHouwing/gittest/remote

C:\Users\JesseHouwing\gittest\repo>git push network main
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 218 bytes | 218.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To C:/Users/JesseHouwing/gittest/remote
 * [new branch]      main -> main
```

Comment: The trick is indeed the use of the " /"  when specifying a file path in a git command, instead of the window "\" . Thanks, back to the fun stuff: writing the codez